# Consolidated realtime mysql backup with master/slave setup or binlog

Tags: mysql, replication, mysqldump, percona, backup

I have 20+ mysql servers and their have low write requirements.

So, I want to see if any way I can replicate the data/binlog from these servers to a single slave so realtime backup purpose.

If I have only a single master, then replication is easy, however, in this case, I have 20+.

Are there any easy way if I don't want to setup 20+ mysql salve on a single server?

Answer (score 1):

Till MySQL 5.6 released version, Multiple master to single slave replication is not possible. This type of replication is under development in MySQL 5.7 version.

you can refer below link:-

[MySQL 5.7 Multi-Source-Replication](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/10/02/mysql-5-7-multi-source-replication/)

Comment: @Howard As an alternative, you have MariaDB 10 multi-source replication: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/multi-source-replication/ or you can setup your own thing in regular MySQL with mysqlbinlog 5.6 remote binlog backup https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlbinlog-backup.html